# Why are binary code converters needed?

Tags: binary

I was wondering why a computer would need binary code converters to convert from BCD to Excess-3 for example. Why is this necessary can't computers just use one form of binary code.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/927/ ?

Comment: That would be really nice, wouldn't it? It would also require you to replace every piece of hardware and every piece of software once a new binary coding system is developed to be the new standard. BCD stems from a time where avoiding the conversion cost was paramount. Unfortunately it's a pain to implement in an arithmethic unit ... and so on

Comment: Binary is so much more than just a string of 1s and 0s..

Answer (score 0):

Some older forms of binary representation persist even after a newer, "better" form comes into use.  For example, legacy hardware that is still in use running legacy code that would be too costly to rewrite.  Word lengths were not standardized in the early years of computing, so machines with words varying from 5 to 12 bits in length naturally will require different schemes for representing the same numbers.

In some cases, a company might persist in using a particular representation for self-compatibility (i.e., with the company's older products) reasons, or because it's an ingrained habit or "the company way."  For example, the use of big-endian representation in Motorola and PowerPC chips vs. little-endian representation in Intel chips.  (Though note that many PowerPC processors support both types of endian-ness, even if manufacturers typically only use one in a product.)

The previous paragraph only really touches upon byte ordering, but that can still be an issue for data interchange.

Even for BCD, there are many ways to store it (e.g., 1 BCD digit per word, or 2 BCD digits packed per byte).  IBM has a clever representation called [zoned decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Zoned_decimal) where they store a value in the high-order nybble which, combined with the BCD value in the low-order nybble, forms an EBCDIC character representing the value.  This is pretty useful if you're married to the concept of representing characters using EBCDIC instead of ASCII (and using BCD instead of 2's complement or unsigned binary).

Tangentially related: IBM mainframes from the 1960s apparently converted BCD into an intermediate form called [qui-binary](http://www.righto.com/2015/10/qui-binary-arithmetic-how-1960s-ibm.html) before performing an arithmetic operation, then converted the result back to BCD.  This is sort of a Rube Goldberg contraption, but according to the linked article, the intermediate form gives some error detection benefits.

The IBM System/360 (and probably a bunch of newer machines) supported both packed BCD and pure binary representations, though you have to watch out for IBM nomenclature — I have heard an old IBMer refer to BCD as "binary," and pure binary (unsigned, 2's complement, whatever) as "binary coded hex."  This provides a lot of flexibility; some data may naturally be best represented in one format, some in the other, and the machine provides instructions to convert between forms conveniently.

In the case of floating point arithmetic, there are some values that cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point, but can be with BCD or a similar representation.  For example, the number 0.1 has no exact binary floating point equivalent.  This is why BCD and fixed-point arithmetic are preferred for things like representing amounts of currency, where you need to exactly represent things like $3.51 and can't allow floating point error to creep in when adding.

Intended application is important.  Arbitrary precision arithmetic will require a different representation strategy compared to the fixed-width registers in your CPU (e.g., Java's `BigDecimal` class).  Many languages support arbitrary precision (e.g., Scheme, Haskell), though the underlying implementation of arbitrary precision numbers varies.  I'm honestly not sure what is preferable for arbitrary precision, a BCD-type scheme or a denser pure binary representation.  In the case of Java's `BigDecimal`, conversion from binary floating point to `BigDecimal` is best done by first converting to a String — this makes such conversions potentially inefficient, so you really need to know ahead of time whether `float` or `double` is good enough, or whether you really need arbitrary precision, and when.

Another tangent: Groovy, a JVM language, quietly treats all floating point numeric literals in code as `BigDecimal` values, and uses `BigDecimal` arithmetic in preference to `float` or `double`.  That's one reason Groovy is very popular with the insurance industry.

tl;dr There is no one-size-fits-all numeric data type, and as long as that remains the case (probably the heat death of the universe), you'll need to convert between representations.